# Hide Searchbar without leaving blank space when using UISearchController in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

The default behavior for UISearchController when you create it in code with:

self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc]

with iOS 13 seems to be rather than hiding the searchBar to show it at the top or above a tableview immediately below the navigation view.

[image]

Then when the searcher becomes firstResponder, the searchBar moves up inside the navigation view as follows:

[image]

providing you have set

```
self.navigationItem.searchController = self.searchController;
```

You can hide the searchBar by changing the hidden property to YES as follows:

```
self.searchController.searchBar.hidden = NO;
```

However, it leaves white space.

[image]

To counter this I have tried manually moving the Tableview and buttons upwards, however, that seems to have no effect.

How can I hide the searchBar prior to it becoming active without leaving a white space where it is hidden?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: How will it become active if it's hidden?

Comment: Try to set the `searchController.searchBar = nil`, completely remove it and add new one each time user touch the search button

Comment: @cora There is a UIBarButton or search button to show it (magnifying glass) in navigation view

Comment: @Tj3n  Tried that but gives Assignment to readonly property error